# Android onclicklistener not called after hidekeyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my layout, I have an `editText` and a `button`.

I what that the keyboard shows or hides if the `editText` gains or loses focus. To achieve this, I added an `OnFocusChangeListener` to the `editText` and I hide or show the keyboard looking at the `hasFocus` flag.

The problem is that, when the `editText` has focus and the keyboard is visible if I touch in the button, the `focusChangeListener` is called, I hide the keyboard but the `button` `onClickListener` is not called. I have to click the button again after the keyboard is hidden.

If instead, I had a delay (`postDelayed({ hideKeyboard() }, 500)`) when the editText looses focus, the `onClickListener` is called.

Adding a delay seems like a hack. How can I hide the keyboard and still receive the button click?

Answer (score 0):

hide keyboard manually when clicking on the button using this method and remove focus listener

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view != null) {
         InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

for focus on `EditText` on startup of the screen you can use `<requestFocus/>` in xml